# npm start throws ELIFECYCLE error , using MongoDB and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm

I have been following a guide on setting up a MongoDB server. However, suddenly I was unable to start localhost:3000 by npm start. It loads, and is up for about 5-10 seconds, then I get an error code ELIFECYCLE. I tried every step mentioned by others , npm cache clean --force , npm install , deleting package-lock.json file and npm install after , deleteing node-modules. Nothing seems to fix my problem.

this is the debug log I get :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\NodeJS\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\musta\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~prestart: shopping-cart@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: shopping-cart@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\musta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Other\Projects\Code\Powershell\shopping-cart\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;D:\NodeJS\;C:\Users\musta\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\musta\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: CWD: D:\Other\Projects\Code\Powershell\shopping-cart
10 silly lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node ./bin/www' ]
11 silly lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: shopping-cart@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\musta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\musta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid shopping-cart@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Other\Projects\Code\Powershell\shopping-cart
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "D:\\NodeJS\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\musta\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error shopping-cart@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the shopping-cart@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Also, the guide i've been following first used a code in the index.js file that looked like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('D:/Other/Projects/Code/Powershell/shopping-cart/models/product');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.find(function(err, docs) {
    var productChunks = [];
    var chunkSize = 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
           productChunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products: productChunks });
  });
});
```

However, when I use it , the localhost:3000 page just keeps loading until I get the same error as above, so I have been using the code that was used earlier in the guide which worked up until the npm start error. The working code was :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('D:/Other/Projects/Code/Powershell/shopping-cart/models/product');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var products = Product.find();
  res.render('shop/index.hbs', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Are these issues related? I have searched all over github and stackoverflow and the comments on the youtube guide, but can not seem to find the issue.

Any help would be appreciated , thanks!

Comment: It seems that you are getting the error when you introduce a query to MongoDB. Make sure the database is up and ready.

Comment: @AlexisPavlidis it doesn't seem to shutdown the localhost now when I have the mongoDB server up (./mongod) , which I find weird since it didn't need it before, but thanks for pointing that out. Now I tried to use npm start with the first code snippet for the index.js file that I posted under the debug log, and got a new message saying this : 

      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for your second problem, You just need a `MiddleWares` in your root file install dependency `body-parser` and add below code

```
//Middlewares for bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: do I add the entire snippet? from /middlewares? and in which file? I would guess the app.js file right?

Comment: added it and this is what I got                     <code>app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
        ^
ReferenceError: bodyParser is not defined</code>

Comment: install `npm i body-parser` and in your `app.js` file import it as `const bodyParser = require('body-parser');` and the use above code

Comment: Fixed it, I had forgot or removed the'' module.exports = router;'' at the bottom of the page, thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Can you post your `app.js` file in questions? Okayy!!